# useCallback vs Class Methods [Perf Comparison]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have recently started to use hooks and was migrating existing class components to hooks. Amidst several perf benefits of using hooks, one aspect which I could not grasp was how callbacks are passed.

Hooks introduces `useCallback` which provides a memoized callback so that every re-render need not unnecessarily generate a new method. But still upon going through the [API's setup](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L611), I can see that for every render it still does a lot.

Class API on the other hand provides a simple way of binding a callback once and hence there would not be any additional mixins for every render.

Sample code for comparison :

```
/**
 * Hooks
 */

function Test() {
  const handleCallback = React.useCallback(() => {
    /**
     * Callback handler implementation
     */
  }, [/** deps */]);

  return <ChildComponent callback={handleCallback} />;
}


/**
 * Class API
 */
class Test extends React.Component {
  handleCallback = () => {
    /**
     * Callback handler implementation
     */
  };

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent callback={this.handleCallback} />;
  }
}
```

Quoting from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook):

> Hooks let you organize side effects in a component by what pieces are related (such as adding and removing a subscription), rather than forcing a split based on lifecycle methods.

- Is this perf hit the expected tradeoff of having all pieces in one place ?
- Would there be any scenario where you would use an inline callback as it would always result in re-render of children. In that case isn't `useCallback` [almost always needed](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/function-apis/active-rfcs/0000-function-api.md#comparison-with-react-hooks) ?

Comment: Yes, there will be a GC pressure, creating new functions on every render, and immediately that function is thrashed, if the the dependencies don't change.

Having a `useCallback` is dependent on how the closure is created, if you have dependencies for the `useCallback` that keep changing for every keystroke or input then a `useCallback` just adds a memoize compute burden. So it depends on the use case.

Comment: Even if the `deps` don't change, `useCallback` doesn't just return back the memoized function in `O(1)`. There are few other checks as well which run on every render. Have linked source. This is where I prefer class API which binds a fn once.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant by the GC pressure, (creating new functions and thrashing them even if the deps don't change). My personal opinion is that if you've chose React this shouldn't be a concern as you've chosen the vdom route, which is a big performance hit compared to imperative frameworks such as jquery. This should be a minimal overhead compared to vdom bookkeeping.

Comment: This link should also throw more light.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render
The real performance optimisation that react folks should consider is moving out of vdom. A compiler that can convert jsx -> native dom instructions. Every other optimisation seems like penny wise pound foolish to me.

Comment: `svelte` does just that, by imperative DOM manipulation. But within react itself, I am now considering sticking with classes for components where there are lot of callbacks. `useCallback` is too big a tradeoff for complex components. But nertheless, hooks are brilliant in small components.